# Trouble with Xcode! Expected ";" after method prototype

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm just starting out with Xcode and I am making a simple soundboard app with some of my friends.

I am having issues with the first line. I have written the code and I am pretty sure it is correct, but I cannot understand why this is here! I am getting an "Expected ';' after method prototype" and have tried everything to fix it, just inserting the semicolon gives me 3 more errors. here is my code

```
'#import "ViewController.h"'

@interface ViewController ()

// Sound for Ben
- (IBAction)playsound1 { // this is where the error is. It is not on any other line

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Ben" ofType:@"mp3"];
AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];

theAudio.delegate=self;
[theAudio play];
}
// Sound for Bruno
- (IBAction)playsound2 {

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Bruno" ofType:@"mp3"];
AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL    fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];

theAudio.delegate=self;
[theAudio play];
}
// Sound for Homer
- (IBAction)playsound3 {

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Homer" ofType:@"mp3"];
AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];

theAudio.delegate=self;
[theAudio play];
}
// Sound for Jon
- (IBAction)playsound4 {

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Jon" ofType:@"mp3"];
AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];

theAudio.delegate=self;
[theAudio play];
}
// Sound for Mark
- (IBAction)playsound5 {

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Mark" ofType:@"mp3"];
AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];

theAudio.delegate=self;
[theAudio play];
}
// Sound for Mikey
- (IBAction)playsound6 {

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Mikey" ofType:@"mp3"];
AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL     fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];

theAudio.delegate=self;
[theAudio play];
}
// Sound for Omar
- (IBAction)playsound7 {

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Omar" ofType:@"mp3"];
AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];

theAudio.delegate=self;
[theAudio play];
}
// Sound for Tom
- (IBAction)playsound8 {

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Tom" ofType:@"mp3"];
AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];

theAudio.delegate=self;
[theAudio play];
}
// Sound for Victor
- (IBAction)playsound9 {

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Victor" ofType:@"mp3"];
AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];

theAudio.delegate=self;
[theAudio play];
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

---

Hey all errors are gone now but when it is run, when i click on a button, it closes and takes me here

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
      @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

it highlights the "return" line in "main.m" in green with a SIGABRT error?

Comment: Please give us a http://www.sscce.org. Otherwise, I can almost ensure that no one will be willing to read all of that. Break it down into smaller pieces. And sometimes, this may even help you find the answer yourself.

Comment: It should be #import "ViewController.h" instead of '#import "ViewController.h"'.

Answer (score 5):

> I am having issues with the first line

Of course you are -- you've got complete functions in your interface section. The interface should include method prototypes only. Method definitions go in the implementation section. You have:

```
@interface ViewController ()

- (IBAction)playsound1 { // this is where the error is. It is not on any other line

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Ben" ofType:@"mp3"];
AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];

theAudio.delegate=self;
[theAudio play];
}
```

That should instead be:

```
@interface ViewController ()

- (IBAction)playsound1;

// ...
@end
```

Followed by:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)playsound1 { // this is where the error is. It is not on any other line
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Ben" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];

    theAudio.delegate=self;
    [theAudio play];
}

// ...
@end
```

(I added some indentation for easier reading.)

Comment: Hey all errors are gone now but when it is run, when i click on a button, it closes and takes me here

    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    #import "AppDelegate.h"

     int main(int argc, char *argv[])
      {
          @autoreleasepool {
            return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
        }
    }
it highlights the "return" line in "main.m" in green with a SIGABRT error?

Comment: That's a different problem -- probably best to ask another question. Sounds like your code is throwing an exception, but it's hard to say without more information.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't write the definition of method  in `@interface ... @end`. You can declare only methods. Write your method's definition in `@implementation ....@end` and declare your methods in `@interfaece...@end`.

I think it will be helpful to you.